# Javascript checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issues with the checkbox code i have build.
I am launching a function on change then i use a if statement, but even if the if statement is doing its job it will still launch the function as many times as i clicked it.
So we have a IF statement, and if i select it 10 times it will give me 5 alerts
Ive try'd the one() function, but it is not a solution.

```
checkbox = $("#checkbox").attr('value');
$('#del').prop('disabled', true);
$("#checkbox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {

        $('#del').prop('disabled', false);
        $("#del").one("click", function () {
            var id = checkbox;
            alert("Checkbox selected & clicked del");

        }); //end del click
    } //end if
    else {
        $('#del').prop('disabled', true);
    } //end if
}); //end checkbox click
```

Comment: Add HTML and complete JS code

Comment: That is because of the nested event binding.

Comment: Try `$('#del').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#del').prop('disabled', false);
        alert('Checkbox selected & clicked del');
    } else {
        $('#del').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **unbind** function like following

```
var checkbox = $("#checkbox").attr('value');
$('#del').prop('disabled', true);
$("#checkbox").change(function () {
if (this.checked) {
    $('#del').prop('disabled', false);
    $("#del").unbind('click');   //unbind click event
    $("#del").click(function () {
        var id = checkbox;
        alert("Checkbox selected & clicked del");

    }); //end del click
} //end if
else {
    $('#del').prop('disabled', true);
} //end if
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, i definitly need some more basic training. Thanks allot!

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```js
var checkbox = $("#checkbox").attr('value');
$('#del').prop('disabled', true);
$("#checkbox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(function () {
            $('#del').prop('disabled', false);
            $("#del").one("click", function () {
                var id = checkbox;
                console.log("Checkbox selected & clicked del");
            }); //end inside function.
        }); //end del clickdel click
    } //end if
    else {
        $('#del').prop('disabled', true);
    } //end if
}); //end checkbox click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Checkbox
<button id="del">Delete</button>
```

Code suggested by @tushar

```js
var checkbox = $("#checkbox").attr('value');
$('#del').prop('disabled', true);
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
  $('#del').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});

$("#del").one("click", function() {
  console.log("Checkbox selected & clicked del");
}); //end inside function.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Checkbox
<button id="del">Delete</button>
```

If you notice, I have moved, click binding outside if. This is because, when ever condition was true a new event was binded and hence multiple alerts were fired.

Comment: If that's what OP wants, then use `$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $('#del').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});` **only**. Check [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/py4ph8w6/)

Comment: My bad, will remove that extra function in `if`.

Comment: This is giving me the same problems 10 clicks 5 pop ups. not a solution.!

Comment: Yes! it is working on there...i will check why it is not working here later, i need some sleep.

Comment: @PeterGruppelaar please check 2nd snippet. First one represents your code.

Answer (score 0):

So you need somwething like this:

```
checkbox = $("#checkbox").attr('value');
$('#del').prop('disabled', true);

$("#checkbox").change(function(){ // this will enable/disable del button
    if(this.checked){
      $('#del').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
 });


 $("#del").on( "click", function(){ // this will add click event to del button but lonly once
        var id    = checkbox;
        alert("Checkbox selected & clicked del");

        }); //end del click
```

So in short: you need to separate your responsibility:

- First block will enable/disable `del` button.
- Second block will execute `onclick` on `del` button.

Comment: I havent try'd this but i think it will have the same issue becouse javascript remembers the click count, and will execute the function if true.
This was the fix...$("#del").unbind('click');   //unbind click event